# high_voltage gem not working for URLs not beginning with /pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I can't seem to get [thoughtbot's High Voltage gem](https://github.com/thoughtbot/high_voltage) to work for URLs that don't start with `/pages`. For URLs like `www.example.com/pages/company/about`, it works perfect. When I add this route:

```
match '/company/about' => 'high_voltage/pages#show', :id => 'about'
```

I get an internal server error:

```
Started GET "/company/about" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-10-09 18:03:45 -0700
Processing by HighVoltage::PagesController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"about"}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 2ms

ActionController::RoutingError (No such page: about):
  high_voltage (1.2.0) app/controllers/high_voltage/pages_controller.rb:9:in `block in <class:PagesController>'
  activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/rescuable.rb:80:in `call'
  activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/rescuable.rb:80:in `rescue_with_handler'
  actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:15:in `rescue_with_handler'
```

However, if I just put the `about.html.erb` page inside `app/views/pages/about.html.erb`, then everything works as expected with this route:

```
match '/:id' => 'high_voltage/pages#show'
```

or this route works too:

```
match '/about' => 'high_voltage/pages#show', :id => 'about'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jferris at GitHub informed me I have to make the id 'company/about' above. And that worked.